# Get List of Videos that Only Have Subtitles Youtube API

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I have a python code that could search videos using Youtube API.
My output goal is to retrieve videos that have subtitles/CC only, just like search filter on Youtube Web.
[image]

My current code:

```
videos = []
def get_videos_by_query(query: str, maxResults: int = 50, pageToken: str = None):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME,
              YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
              developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    try:
        search_response = youtube.search().list(
            part="id,snippet",
            order='date',
            maxResults=maxResults,
            pageToken=pageToken,
            q=query
            ).execute()

        for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
            if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
                videoId = search_result["id"]["videoId"]
                data = videoId
                videos.append(data)

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's called: ***"isCC": True or False, # Indicates whether the track contains closed captions for the deaf and hard of hearing. The default value is false.***. Read up on [v3.captions](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/python/latest/youtube_v3.captions.html#list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs of [`Search.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) API endpoint, for to achieve the desired filtering on the result set obtained, you should use the following parameter:

> [**videoCaption**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#videoCaption) (string)
>
> The videoCaption parameter indicates whether the API should filter video search results based on whether they have captions. If you specify a value for this parameter, you must also set the [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) parameter's value to `video`.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - `any` – Do not filter results based on caption availability.
> - `closedCaption` – Only include videos that have captions.
> - `none` – Only include videos that do not have captions.

Consequently, do replace your call to `youtube.search().list()` above with the following one:

```
search_response = youtube.search().list(
        part="id,snippet",
        order='date',
        type='video',
        videoCaption='closedCaption',
        maxResults=maxResults,
        pageToken=pageToken,
        q=query
        ).execute()
```

Note that by this change, the following piece of code becomes superfluous:

```
if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
```

This is because, by having `type='video'` in the invocation of the API endpoint, each item of the result set obtained is necessarily referring to a video.